# Are there any good links and references for learning how to create an Appium Python Framework?

Tags: python, test-automation-framework, appium

Are there any good links and references for learning how to create an `Appium Python Framework`?

There seem to be a lot of `Java` information out there, but `Python` seem to have a lot less available resources.

Any good links to learn Python also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learn Appium using multiple resources, I found online stuff and experimental project for android & iOS App. Just google "Appium tutorial", I will suggest don't stick with any programing language(like python), it's just a medium to express code. In my case, I learn Appium using JAVA but I implemented using C#, You can cover up if you have good command over your language(Python). There will be plenty of links to pages showing basics, many focus on different aspects so it's useful to read a number of them. I always found the official resource helpful, The [Appium documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/) is pretty good as well, they have also covered Advanced concept there. Appium is open source, so you can always browse the source if you need more clarity on how something works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, nice tutorials  and explanations https://testautomationu.applitools.com/learningpaths.html?id=web-ui-python-path

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good YouTube video series by Raghav Pal on Python:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2VXCEfIgC0&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L_IH9bmssFw47zHeLm1gsxo